# Embedding of a Graph in a Sphere

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, algebraic-topology, planar-graphs

Let $G$ be a finite connected graph and $f:G\to S^2$ be an embedding of $G$ into $S^2$ (we are assuming that $G$ *can* be embedded in $S^2$). Think of the graph as a $1$-dimensional CW complex.

> Is it true that each component of $S^2\setminus f(G)$ is homeomorphic to a disc?

For simplicity one may assume that the graph is simple and that each vertex has degree at least 2 (if this makes life easier).

I want to read planarity of graphs, but the graph theory texts I have access to do not treat the topological aspects rigorously. Can anyone suggest me a book where planarity is treated rigorously?

Comment: Is the graph a finite graph? And what is an embedding?

Comment: Yeah I should have mentioned that the graph is finite. A graph is viewed as a 1-dimensional CW complex. The usual definition of embedding of a topological space into the other applies.

Comment: Here's a few things that will really help in obtaining full rigor. First, some 2-dimensional geometric topology: the Jordan Curve Theorem and the Schöflies theorem; the latter theorem is exactly what answers your question in the affirmative when $G$ is a circle. Also some algebraic topology will be helpful, particularly the Alexander Duality Theorem, of which the Jordan Curve Theorem is a corollary; in general you use it to count the number of components of $S^1 \setminus f(G)$, which equals $\text{rank}(G)+1$.

Comment: @LeeMosher That sounds like I have to do a lot of heavy lifting for this problem.

Comment: That is so, particularly keeping in mind how deep the simple case of the circle is, requiring the Schönflies Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The embedding of graphs into all types of surfaces is discussed in extensive detail in Gross and Tucker's *[Topological Graph Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486417417)*. I read the first two or three chapters, but I don't remember if the answer to your specific question was addressed -- that being said, I would be very surprised if it wasn't, since the book covers embeddings in surfaces far more exotic than the sphere.